# PHP function reference using args

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm new to PHP. I'm trying to hide certain dashboard nav items from certain users (editors). I've added this to the functions, which has hidden it for all users:

```
<?php
function remove_menus(){
  remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' );          //Comments
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus' );
?>
```

It says [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) you can use 'current_user_can' to pinpoint certain users but I'm unsure how to use both together. 
So far I've tried:

```
function remove_menus(){
    current_user_can(
    remove_menu_page( 'editor', 'edit-comments.php' );          //Comments
) );
}
```

and

```
function remove_menus(){
current_user_can( array(
remove_menu_page( 'editor', 'edit-comments.php' );          //Comments
) );
}
```

..but from looking at other functions, they seem to in brackets with => inbetween so I'm presuming I'm using this function the wrong way.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I thought it was self-written code, and I was thus about to advice you not to follow that route - then I realised it was Wordpress. Sorry, WP is so convoluted and irrational that its mere name gives me headache :/

Comment: Look closely at the examples on the page you're linking to. You're supposed to use it like: `if (current_user_can('edit_pages')) remove_menu_page(...)`. Also look at the list of possible capabilities you can pass to the function, I don't know if `'edit_pages'` is the capability you're looking for.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to make `remove_menus` more generic--e.g. allow a number of different arguments that would allow you to remove different menus--or alternatively, make the function name more specific, e.g. `remove_edit_comments_menu`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First answer, very simple , use logic "OR" operator:

```
            <?php 
            function remove_menus(){
                if( current_user_can('editor') || current_user_can('administrator') ) {  // stuff here for admins or editors
                   remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' );  //stuff here for editor and administrator
                }
            } ?>
```

If you want to check more than two roles, you can check if the roles of current user is inside an array of roles, something like:

```
        <?php 
        function remove_menus(){
            $user = wp_get_current_user();
            $allowed_roles = array('editor', 'administrator', 'author');
            if( array_intersect($allowed_roles, $user->roles ) ) { 
                remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' ); //stuff here for allowed roles
            } 
        } ?>
```

However, current_user_can can be used not only with users role name, but also with capabilities. So, once both editors and administrators can edit pages, your life can be easier checking for that capabilities:

```
        <?php 
        function remove_menus(){
            if( current_user_can('edit_others_pages') ) {  
                remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' );// stuff here for user roles that can edit pages: editors and administrators
            } 
        }
        ?>
```

Have a look [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) for more info on capabilities.